# Kendo Grid Custom Editor Dropdown is not accessible in Popup Mode

Tags: model-view-controller, grid, kendo-ui

I am using the Kendo Grid where i need to display dropdownlist as one of the column in the grid to allow users to select State. Here the source of the State can be different for each record. The source of the state is different based on TaskInstanceId property of the record.

The problem i am having is in the popup edit mode the dropdownlist column is not being displayed. And in the inline edit mode dropdownlist is not being displayed until i go in the edit mode. Until i go into edit mode it displays textbox with no value in the textbox.

Please find the sample project attached with this email.

Regards,
Sanjay Patel

Comment: For displaying the value of `State` based on `TaskInstanceId` you might define a function in the `schema.model` that computes the value of `State`.

Comment: Are you wanting something similar to this example? http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/toolbar-template.html

Comment: or probably you want something like http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html